# Why does $ -[(1-p)^2]^i = [1-(1-p)^2]$ where $[(1-p)^2]^i] = P(\min(X,Y) > i)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The context of the problem:

*X and Y are independent random variables, geometrically distributed with parameter p.*

Without any further information I am asked to determine the formula for: $P(\min(X, Y) = i)$

Modelling  $P(\min(X,Y) > i)$ is done by multiplying the marginal probabilities of $\min(X)>i$ and $\min(Y)>i$ (as they are independent) which leads to : $P(X>i  \text{ and } Y>i) = [(1-p)^2]^i$

The solution for the problem is the following : $P(\min(X,Y) > i-1) - P(\min(X,Y) > i) = P(\min(X,Y) = i)$

The argumentation for this solution I understand however, the formula in the solutions simplifies to the following:

$[(1-p)^2]^{i-1} -  [(1-p)^2]^i$ where $-[(1-p)^2]^i$ simplifies to $[1-(1-p)^2]$

This equation is transformed in this way due to the properties of the geometric distribution however I am still struggling to understand how does this work. Could someone explain as to why and how?

Comment: Do you understand that $P(X>i)=(1-p)^i$? Do you understand that $a^{i-1}-a^i=a^{i-1}(1-a)$ for $a=(1-p)^2$? If so then what is it that you do not understand?

Comment: @drhab You answered my question, I did not realize that the expression was factorised.